# include header file in this way, is this a good practice?

Tags: c, header

In gumbo html parser source code, I saw some strange use case of `#include` like this. They just include header file in an array definition block.

```c
const char* kGumboTagNames[] = {
#include "tag_strings.h"
    "",  // TAG_UNKNOWN
    "",  // TAG_LAST
};

static const unsigned char kGumboTagSizes[] = {
#include "tag_sizes.h"
    0,  // TAG_UNKNOWN
    0,  // TAG_LAST
};
```

and then in the `tag_string.h` file lists all legal html tags,

```
"html",
"head",
"title",
"base",
"link",
"meta",
"style",
"script",
"noscript",
...
...
```

I know it works, but still want to know if this is a traditional way to import external data, or it's just a unusual hack out?

Comment: It is a way that exists. Somewhat awkward, but can solve problems. Could consider naming it not `.h` but.. say `.inc`. Because `.h` is assumed to contain valid C code.

Comment: It can be useful if `tag_strings.h` is generated from other data. If so, that generation is probably part of the build process.

Comment: It is probably because those header files are machine-generated.

Comment: I would not call them `.h` files as they do not contain the valid C source.

Comment: @MOehm yes. there is a comment `Generated via "gentags.py src/tag.in".`

Comment: @lan Abbott if those header files are machine-generated, then it makes sense, but why?

Comment: @shen Why what? How would you include some auto-generated data into your source code otherwise?

Comment: With newer languages, metaprogramming is all the rage. The C preprocessor is rather limited. You can play tricks with it, but that only goes so far, and preprocessing data is often offloaded to an external procedure. It's easier to generate only data, no C code, that's why the `#include` goes into the "body" of the definition. The processing in your case is simple: It just generates strings and the associated lengths, but you could do something more complicated. For example you could create a perfect hash with `gperf`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There's many ways to load auto-generated data. But in this way, it's super fast.

Comment: Thanks @MOehm I get the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a decent and somewhat traditional way to use `#include`, ***if*** the array contents you're including has been automatically generated by some other process.  (There are other ways of doing it, though, as I'll mention below.)

It is a classic tradeoff.  Most of the time, a good rule that's worth following is that you should use the preprocessor *only* in straightforward, traditional ways, because when you start getting "tricky" it's all too easy to create an unholy mess.

But sometimes, you have an array whose contents you really want to generate using some automatic, external process.  Copying and pasting the array definition into your source file would be tedious and error-prone, and you might have to keep redoing it as the array needed updating.  Figuring out a way to automate the process is worth doing, and might even be worth violating the "no tricky preprocessor abuse" rule.

To make this work you will usually want to have some automatic process (perhaps an awk, sed, perl, or python script) that generates the included file with the correct syntax.  If you're using `make` or something like it, you can have that step automatically performed whenever the actual source data for the array changes.  For instance, in the example you gave, you might have an original "source file" `tags.list` containing lines like

```
html
head
title
```

and then in your Makefile use something like `sed 's/.*/"&",'` to create the include file with the proper string initializer syntax.  That way you don't force the folks who are updating the list to remember to always use the right quotes and commas.

Also, as other commentators have suggested, you should probably give the file a name ending in something other than `.h`, to make clear that it's not an ordinary header file containing complete, valid C declarations.  Better possibilities in this case would be `.tab`, `.inc`, or `.arr`.

With a little more work, though, you could avoid the "hack" and do things just about 100% conventionally.  If you tweaked your script to add the line `const char* kGumboTagNames[] = {` at the beginning of the generated file, and `};` at the end, you could give it a name ending in `.c`, and just *compile* it, rather than including it.  (This approach, however, would involve its own tradeoff, in that it would constrain the array to being global, not static or local.)

Footnote: In some languages -- and even in C and C++, under some circumstances -- the comma is used as a *separator*, and you're not allowed to have one after the last element of a list.  But in array initializers, you are allowed to have that trailing comma, and it turns out to be a pretty nice and useful freedom, precisely because it allows you to use straightforward techniques like the one described here, without the nuisance of having to insert an explicit extra step to get rid of the comma after the last element in the list.